# Work out Start Time + Hours with working days and times

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have the following problem:

In **G4** I have `19/01/2016 10:00`

In **F4** I have the value `200 (units)`

In **E4** I have the value `38 (minutes)`

I want to calculate `G4 + (E4*F4)` i.e. `19/1/16 10:00 + 7,600 minutes` but based on a working week of:

`Monday to Thursday 8am-5pm` & `Friday 8am-1pm`

therefore showing the value of `09/02/2016 13:40`

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, I am trying to help a friend out who wants to calculate how long it will take to produce x amount of a certain product that his company produces.

Comment: I don't think there would be am easy easy for that, having different number of working hours really makes your problem complicated. You can do it with a couple of support cells (calculate number of minutes left until end of day / week), or need to write a custom function (macro).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the problem is:

- There is a set production schedule that only occurs during certain time periods on certain days
- We will ignore down time, lunch, breaks, etc. and assume the production line is running the entire time during that work period
- We have a given start time, number of units to produce, and time to produce each unit
- We need to figure out when the production run will be finished

---

### STEP 1

**Setup a table for your schedule**

Make a table that has a two week schedule. We needs it to be two weeks long because that way we can pick the first matching start date (like a Tuesday) and then include the next 7 rows and know that we have a full work week (like a Tuesday - Monday). If you didn't have the schedule twice and you started on a Friday,  you'd get one day and then a bunch of blank rows. Be sure to include Saturday and Sunday. Here's a snapshot of the table I called `tblSchedule`:

[image: tblSchedule]

... and the CSV version (time is shown as a fraction of a day):

```
Weekday,Day,Start Time,Work Hours
1,Sunday,0,0
2,Monday,0.333333333333333,9
3,Tuesday,0.333333333333333,9
4,Wednesday,0.333333333333333,9
5,Thursday,0.333333333333333,9
6,Friday,0.333333333333333,5
7,Saturday,0,0
1,Sunday,0,0
2,Monday,0.333333333333333,9
3,Tuesday,0.333333333333333,9
4,Wednesday,0.333333333333333,9
5,Thursday,0.333333333333333,9
6,Friday,0.333333333333333,5
7,Saturday,0,0
```

---

### STEP 2

**Setup a table for your production runs**

You already have the start of this one. We're going to add a few fields and I'm assuming you're using an actual table (Insert ribbon > Table). If you don't, this will all still work but understanding the formulas will be more difficult because it'll be a bunch of cell references instead of field names. Tables are awesome. Here's a snapshot of what I called `tblProduction`: (Note that my system uses the non-ISO format for dates of `m/d/yyyy` because America.)

[image: tblProduction]

... and the CSV header row:

```
Min / Unit,Qty Units,Start,Production Time (hrs),Weeks,Days,Hours,End
```

---

### STEP 3

**Add your formulas**

**Production Time (hrs)**

```
=[@[Min / Unit]]*[@[Qty Units]]/60
```

This one is pretty self-explanatory. The only trick is that we're converting from minutes to hours because the rest of the math will use hours.

**Weeks**

```
=[@[Production Time (hrs)]]/(SUM(tblSchedule[Work Hours])/2)
```

This just converts from hours to work weeks. Note that we have to divide the sum of all work hours in a week by 2 because our schedule is two weeks and not just one.

**Days**

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(tblSchedule[Work Hours],WEEKDAY([@Start])-1,0,ROW($A$1:$A$7)))-ROUND((((((TIME(HOUR([@Start]),MINUTE([@Start]),SECOND([@Start])))-INDEX(tblSchedule[Start Time],WEEKDAY([@Start])-1))*24))+(MOD([@Weeks],1)*(SUM(tblSchedule[Work Hours])/2))),2))>=0,0),0)-1
```

This one is the big monster. It can be broken into several pieces if that helps but I was trying to keep it as a nice finished product and I figured your friend wouldn't want all the extra columns in there. If you were going to break it out, it might look something like this:

[image: Expanded Days Formula]

... and the CSV header row:

```
Days,Start Time,Work Start Time,Hours in Last Week,Hours from Start of Last Week
```

Start Time

```
=TIME(HOUR([@Start]),MINUTE([@Start]),SECOND([@Start]))
```

Work Start Time

```
=INDEX(tblSchedule[Start Time],WEEKDAY([@Start])-1)
```

Hours in Last Week

```
=MOD([@Weeks],1)*(SUM(tblSchedule[Work Hours])/2)
```

Hours from Start of Last Week

```
=ROUND(((([@[Start Time]]-[@[Work Start Time]])*24)+[@[Hours in Last Week]]),2)
```

That last formula is the one we really need. If you expand into these columns, the formula for `Days` would be this:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(tblSchedule[Work Hours],WEEKDAY([@Start])-1,0,ROW($A$1:$A$7)))-[@[Hours from Start of Last Week]])>=0,0),0)-1
```

The basic idea is to find the first day in the schedule when the total work hours from the start day is more than the number of hours we need to finish the production. That's what `MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((SUBTOTAL()-[Hours Left])>=0,0),0)-1` does. The `SUBTOTAL` function does some magic with `OFFSET` and returns an array of values. Those values are the total work hours by the end of the first day, second day, third day, etc. Subtract the hours left we need to work and you get either positive or negative numbers (or zero, hence the `>=0` instead of just `>0`). `INDEX` returns an array of `FALSE` and `TRUE` so `MATCH` finds the first `TRUE` value. Since we're figuring out how many *more* days we need than just the first day, subtract one at the end. It's a complicated process to get to a single number between 0 and 6.

**Hours**

```
=(MOD([@Weeks],1)*(SUM(tblSchedule[Work Hours])/2))-IF([@Days]=0,0,SUM(OFFSET(tblSchedule[Work Hours],WEEKDAY([@Start])-1,0,[@Days])))
```

The start of this one is just like the `Hours in Last Week` formula we used above. The `IF` statement at the end subtracts out the work hours between the first day and the last day, exclusive. If we start Tuesday and end Friday, subtract out Wednesday and Thursday. This gives us the hours we have to work on the last day (which might be the same as the first day).

**End**

```
=[@Start]+7*TRUNC([@Weeks])+[@Days]+[@Hours]/24
```

Start Date + 7 * (number of weeks as an integer, dropping the fraction) + Days + (hours converted to a decimal value of days) = Date and Time and the end of production.

---

### SUMMARY

Yes, these are some big formulas. However, I've made it fairly easy to maintain and tested a couple different edge cases so I think it all works correctly. If your friend wants a neat sheet, use the big formula for `Days`. If he wants one he can explain more easily, use the version with several helper formulas.

---

### ADDITION

For what it's worth, your friend can also add in real world factors like expected scrap rate and down time (including planned breaks). Here's an example that accounts for those *before* they get fed into the complicated formulas above.

[image: Reject Rate]

**Reject Rate**

Typed in manually as percentages.

**Production Time (hrs)**

```
=[@[Min / Unit]]*([@[Qty Units]]/(1-[@[Reject Rate]]))/60
```

[image: Downtime]

**Standard Hours**

Typed in manually. Same values as used in original examples above.

**Downtime**

Typed in manually as a number of hours, not as a percentage. You could modify it to be a percentage but hours were easier to show.

**Work Hours**

```
=[@[Standard Hours]]-[@Downtime]
```

Note that this may screw up the actual end time on the last day of production. The formulas will assume you start at 8am and work for X hours when really there's a break in the middle somewhere. It'll still work for an approximation, though.